# Error term in Bombieri-Vinogradov theorem

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-progressions

In [Primes in tuples I](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25662161), in the proof of Proposition 5 (on p. 854) the authors use the "trivial estimate"
$$ E'(N, q) \le \frac{2N}q \log N \quad \text{for $q \le N$}$$
where
$$ E'(N, q) = \max_{(a,q)=1} \left| \vartheta(x;q,a) - \frac x{\varphi(q)} \right| $$
and
$$ \vartheta(x;q,a) = \sum_{p \le x, \; p \equiv a \,\text{mod}\, q} \log p $$
as usual.
I would like to understand how one obtains this estimate.
I tried using the fact that
$$ \liminf_{n \to \infty} \frac{\varphi(n) \log \log n}n = \mathrm e^{-\gamma} > 0. $$
However, I am hesitant to call this fact trivial and even if I do use it, in the original statement I get a constant which is worse than $2$.
(I know that the constants don't really matter here, but it makes me feel like there should be a different argument.)

Comment: This should follow from a trivial estimate on $\theta(x;q,a)$ where one assumes that every integer congruent to $a\pmod q$ is prime.

Comment: The weaker result $\varphi(n)\gg n/\log\log n$ would be relatively trivial than the one you quoted